# highcharts rescale yaxis aftr addSeries

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am adding a series using javascript (addSeries), when I do this with larger values, the yaxis is not rescaling.

http://jsfiddle.net/7YhYT/11/

To replicate our problem, check the check box next to Joel Twitter-Followers

Then you will see the y axis go zero to 85.

Then click the check box next to "Joel Twitter-Followers Of Followers", the axis stays at 85, but if you resize your browser window it fixes itself.

I asked this on the highcharts forum, but no no help yet:

http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=19853&p=79468&hilit=yaxis&sid=7f778241b204cae137b1525607c13a99#p79468

Any ideas?
thanks
Joel

Comment: I am getting this error in your fiddle, 
`$j("#trends_select_all")[0] is undefined`
@`$j("#trends_select_all")[0].checked = false;`
Fix the issue for better help

Comment: When do you get the error? It works fine for me..

Comment: I had 2 other people try the jsfiddle and no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your real problem is, since your jsFiddle example did not work for me.

But here is my sample for a similar scenario, clicking the button adds a new series
http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/hb2jj/

If this is not what you are looking for, can you reproduce your issue in my fiddle example? and get back to me